# Insert and select date from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, database, sql-server-2000

I have got the following exception when try to select data from SQL Server or inserting data in in with a C# windows application. I am passing the date in where clause of select query in single quotes like this '16/03/2011' The exception message is shown below:

> The conversion of a char data type to
>   a datetime data type resulted in an
>   out-of-range datetime value.

Is there any perfect solution for inserting and selecting date from sqlserver database irrelevant to the operating system. i.e. that works on both Italian and English OS.

Comment: I would **always** use the ISO-8601 format (`YYYYMMDD`) - that one works regardless of your language and regional settings! So try `20110316` instead of `16/03/2011`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use stored procs, or parameterized queries, you might want to format the date in a yyyy-mm-dd format. Ex. `'2011-03-16'`

T-SQL SAMPLE

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (SomeDate) VALUES ('2011-03-16')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SomeDate <= '2011-03-16'
```

Also, keep in mind the time portion of the date. If time is not important, then make sure you don't store it, because it could impact your SELECT queries down the road.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, being a developer, I should have RTFM.

Comment: Justin is correct that if you can't use paramaterized queries, this is the way to do it. However, the SqlDataAdapter has been around since .NET 1.1, so you should not have a reason not to use it!!

Answer (score 2):

Use stored procedures, or parameterized queries. These will let you pass in a C# datetime object, and the conversion will be handled automatically for you.

I would suggest starting with the [SQLDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) class. A simple example of this would be:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE myDate = @myDate", someSqlConnection)
{
    da.SelectCommand.Paramaters.Add("@myDate", new DateTime());
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

However, be aware that there are many different ways of achieving your goal. From your question, I would imagine you are creating SQL strings and executing them against your database. This is considered a Bad Practice for lots of reasons (including the one you describe). Read up about ORMs such as Entity Framework or NHibernate.

Comment: I agree with your approach. At a minimum, one should be using parameterized queries. At least this helps prevent SQL Injection.